# Yii2: Conditional fill of Json data

Tags: json, yii2

I have a table ipd_charges like

```
id doctor_name charges_cash charges_cashless
1      1             300         600
2      2             200         400
```

and in my controller the code is like this which is working fine

```
public function actionCharges($id){
    $model= \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['doctor'=>$id]);
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([
        'visit_charges'=>$model->charges_cash,
    ]);
    }
```

Now what I want is to fill the data on condition and tried to modify the above code which is only returning the first condition in either case

```
    public function actionCharges($id){
    $model= \app\models\IpdCharges::findOne(['doctor'=>$id]);
    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('tpa_name')
    ->from('patient_detail') 
    ->innerJoin('daily_ward_entry', 
   'daily_ward_entry.general_regn_no = patient_detail.general_regn_no')
    ->where(['daily_ward_entry.id'=>$id]);

   $command = $query->createCommand();
   $rows = $command->queryAll();



 if ($rows['tpa_name'] === NULL){
    return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([      
        'visit_charges'=>$model->charges_cash,        
    ]);
    }else {
       return \yii\helpers\Json::encode([         
        'visit_charges'=>$model->charges_cashless,
            ]);
       }
    }
```

Need a little clue what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$model1= \app\models\Tpa::findOne(['tpa_name']);
```

You are specifying this condition wrong. You only provide column name without any condition.
Also you need to check `$model` for existence too.

Comment: Dear Arogachev - can you please provide some more insight, how I should go about it. I want to compare the value of column tpa_name whether is NULL or Not Null and then return the values.