# Yii2 how to convert mysql query to yii\db\query

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am using mysql query as

```
SELECT tpa_name
FROM `patient_detail` p, daily_ward_entry d
WHERE d.general_regn_no = p.general_regn_no
AND d.id =3
```

I am getting the result as 1 and Null when d.id =1

But in controller public function actionCharges($id)

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('tpa_name')
    ->from('patient_detail') 
    ->innerJoin('daily_ward_entry', 
   'daily_ward_entry.general_regn_no =    patient_detail.general_regn_no');

   $command = $query->createCommand();
   $rows = $command->queryAll();
    var_dump($rows);exit;
```

when I am viewing the page using daily-ward-entry/charges&id=3 
I am getting the dump values as Null in all cases.
I am scratching my head what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not checking the id condition

Comment: Hi Ali - How can I do it?

Comment: Hi dear Pawan, just: `->from('patient_detail')->...->where(['daily_ward_entry.id'=>$id])`

Comment: Dear Ali, this is working perfect, but still my auto-fill on conditional check is not working as expected.Wierd!

Comment: Hi Dear Ali, I have edited my question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405760/yii2-conditional-fill-of-json-data) to incorporate these changes, but still it is not giving the expected results